# python strip spaces in tuple

Tags: python

I have

```
k= (('answer ', ' Answer the call for a channel(answer )'), ('att_xfer ', ' Attended Transfer(att_xfer )'), ('bind_digit_action ', ' Bind a key sequence or regex to an action.(bind_digit_action )'))
```

I want to strip all extra spaces. How can I do that

Comment: Looks like the problem is further up...

Comment: Do you also want to remove the whitespaces inside the brackets?

Comment: Yeah, want to remove the whitespaces inside the brackets too

Comment: Please define what makes a "space" an "extra space" :)

Answer (score 6):

If you mean "extra spaces" the spaces in the beginning and end of each string:

```
k = tuple(tuple(b.strip() for b in a) for a in k)
```

If you want to remove some other "extra spaces" within the string (such as `(answer )` => `(answer)`), you would have to define more rules.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to remove all whitespace:

```
tuple(tuple("".join(i.split()) for i in a) for a in k)
```

*out:*

```
(('answer', 'Answerthecallforachannel(answer)'),
 ('att_xfer', 'AttendedTransfer(att_xfer)'),
 ('bind_digit_action',
  'Bindakeysequenceorregextoanaction.(bind_digit_action)'))
```

or if you don't need tuples as a result:

```
from itertools import chain
["".join(i.split()) for i in chain.from_iterable(k)]
```

*out:*

```
['answer',
 'Answerthecallforachannel(answer)',
 'att_xfer',
 'AttendedTransfer(att_xfer)',
 'bind_digit_action',
 'Bindakeysequenceorregextoanaction.(bind_digit_action)']
```

Comment: I would guess that `i.translate(None,string.whitespace)` might be slightly faster than `"".join(i.split)` -- Though I haven't done any benchmarking to prove it :)

Comment: Also, `chain.from_iterable(k)` is probably a little nicer than `chain(*k)`.  Both will work (even if a generator expression is passed), but the former won't resolve the generator into a `tuple` first.

Comment: @mgilson -- Thank you for the comments. Replaced `chain(*k)` with `chain.from_iterable(k)`. Also, it seems that `"".join(i.split)` is actually about 10-20% faster. :)

Comment: @root, good to know.  That makes me wonder how `str.translate` is actually implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be this:

```
tuple(map(lambda x:tuple(map(lambda y:y.strip(),x)),k))
```